# How to store subscript and superscript values in Progress OpenEdge?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Is there a way to store subscript and superscript values  in the Progress database, for example, chemical symbols and formulas, such as C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>OH, and is it possible to display them ?
I tried copying from Word and pasting into fill in string fields but it doesn't format correctly, it doesn't recognize subscripted values and it is displayed as C2H5OH.

Comment: There's support for various UTF-versions. I cannot help you much further, perhaps someone else can. Take a look at the Internationalization guide at https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2743.openedge-11-6-product-documentation

Comment: All text format will be lost when stored to the database, as far as I know... I believe in your case, the best alternative is to come up with notation and record it that way.

Comment: @bupereira + Bubba: the database can be in utf-8 format, there's a lot of documentation in the link i provided.

Comment: UTF-8 is a codepage. It does not retain format. He mentioned he did it in MS Word, so I'm guessing he's not using special characters, just formatting the text to appear subscripted. That, I believe, will not be retained.

Comment: @Jensd I will look through the documentation in the link

Comment: @bupereira can you explain what you meant by coming up with a notation and recording it ?

Comment: Also you could consider contacting Progress Support if possible (and taking a look at community.progress.com)

Answer (score 2):

After some testing I've come this far:

1) You need to start your session with startup parameter `-cpinternal utf-8` ie

> prowin32.exe -cpinternal utf8

Depending on your need you might also need to set `-cpstream utf-8` and possibly `-cpcoll basic` (or something else that matches your needs).

**When I did this I had some strange crashes - but that might be because I edited a file saved in another codepage?**

2) You need to get the data into your system (perhaps you already have it?).

I used Word and information found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2082/index.htm) and further explained [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). The subscript font setting are just font settings (not unicode) so don't let that fool you (copy-pasting from your question is exactly the same). Basically you need to write the hexadecimal value of the subscript 2 (2082) in Word and then press Alt + X.

Assuming you want to write the actual data in a Progress based GUI I haven't been successful so far. Perhaps you could look at changing registry values as described in the links and continue along that path. I don't want to do that for just basic testing...

[image]

3) You will need a font with decent support  for these characters. Some fonts don't support them at all!

Segoe UI:

[image]

Default system font (possibly) MS Sans Serif:

[image]

Arial:

[image]

5) Database? I'm unsure if you will need to use CLOB-fields to store this in your database or not. Most likely you shouldn't.

Hope this is enough to at least get you started!

Comment: Code Pages in Progress are extremely confusing IMO, with many startup parameters and statements within the language itself, and nobody on SO or PT seems to have the complete picture, least of all me (though Jensd may be closest). If I have to fix this kind of problem, I block off several hours of frustration. Good luck!

Comment: @Jensd You gave me a starting point so I will try and work from here and maybe find a solution, thank you